# ASP.NET MVC + fluent nNibernate, what IoC tool?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC project where we have decided to use Fluent nHibernate for dataccess. To enable loose coupling we go for a IoC/DI pattern. My questions is what IoC tool to go for. I've tried to find the differences between windsor, ninject, spring, structuremap and unity, but it's difficult to see the benefits each one has to offer. Whats your experience?

Comment: FYI, next time you ask a question like this, phrase it more like: "What should I look for in an IoC to play well with ASP.NET MVC + fluent nHibernate?" You'll get better answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use StructureMap and it's very easy to use. Personally I don't like to configure using xml and StructureMap makes it a breeze to configure using code. It's also very easy to switch different profile if you need to switch implementations.

Answer (score 4):

I use Windsor and I've nothing to complain about. Easy to use, extensible when you need it and a lot of information if you get stuck. But I don't think it matters that much which container you choose. All of them you mention have the common features and there're also adapters for mvc availiable in the mvccontrib project. A switch to another container shouldn't be difficult if you wrap the container in an own class, which is a good practise anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Windsor and love it. There is a built in facility for using NHibernate which allows for simple configuration of logging and connections etc.

If you plan to use FluentNhibernate you have to tell the Windsor facility which assembly has the ConfigurationBuilder.  Mike Hadlow has a great write up on this plus many others on Windsor and NHibernate: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2009/01/integrating-fluent-nhibernate-and.html

Comment: I went for windsor and sharp-architecture. It works perfect. I also did some testing with StructureMap, and there aren't the big differences. When using Microsoft best practices ServiceLocator it's easy to make a switch later.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Munq](http://munq.codeplex.com/) which is lightweight and fast and is a simple way to add a DI Container to MVC3 projects via Nuget. Up to now I haven't found any need to move to a different framework - Munq has been very adequate.

```
PM> install-package Munq.MVC3
```

This adds `App_Start\MunqMvc3Startup.cs` to the project, and this is where dependencies should be registered.