# Good IOC Frameworks to use with asp.net mvc?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ioc-container

I am wondering what good simple IoC frameworks are there for asp.net mvc? that have good documentation and are just easy to get up and going.

Thanks

Comment: Any decent IoC container ought to work well with ASP.NET MVC. Choose the one that best fits your sensibilities.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288/which-c-net-dependency-injection-frameworks-are-worth-looking-into, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148908/which-dependency-injection-tool-should-i-use, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520089/autofac-or-ninject-which-should-i-go-for, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411660/enterprise-library-unity-vs-other-ioc-containers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770039/examples-of-ioc-containers, etc.

Comment: Looks like Aaronaught is right, though the other question is about a year old.  Maybe make this a CW so information can be kept more or less current as frameworks evolve?

Comment: I added a few more dupe links... the other question may be old but I don't think the landscape has really changed much.  The major players are the same - Autofac, Ninject, Windsor, Unity, StructureMap, etc.

Comment: another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532233/asp-net-mvc-fluent-nnibernate-what-ioc-tool

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) and have been very happy with it.

Configuration is mostly done in code so you get compile time checking for your mappings as opposed to programming in XML and hoping for the best.  It also supports XML overrides though so if you absolutely need to leave something to be configured at run/deploy time it's possible.

The [Contrib](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Integration) (not sure what to call it?) portion provides integrations for NHibernate, Moq, etc.  The creator of the project worked at Microsoft for a year on the MEF team so there's some [MEF integration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MefIntegration) as well.

The documentation section of the site is pretty good (though if you don't find what you need there, it probably doesn't exist...yet).  On the up side the [author is on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138206/nicholas-blumhardt) so if you have questions and tag the appropriately you could probably get quality answers.

---

You might also be interested in these two blog posts on organizing the configuration/wiring of your application to be cleaner.

1. [Using MEF and Castle Windsor to improve decoupling in your architecture](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/howardvanrooijen/archive/2009/11/12/using-mef-and-castle-windsor-to-improve-decoupling-in-your-architecture.aspx)
2. [NHibernate and WPF: The GuyWire](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/11/07/nhibernate-and-wpf-the-guywire.aspx) - Although it's written in the context of WPF, the same concept would apply to a webapp.

Answer (score 2):

I use Windsor Castle, other people say that [Structure Map](http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/index.html) is really good, but basically they all do the job

Answer (score 1):

[S#arp Architecture](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/) is admittedly a lot more than just IoC.  It uses [Castle/Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/) for IoC.

I would recommend it as a larger set of best practices for the framework of your MVC application.

Comment: Castle/Windsor official site is weird. Cannot find there any samples of using the container.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) and it is good.

Answer (score 1):

Danial Cazzulino has a [bunch (scrunch?) of screencasts](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/funq-screencast-series-on-how-to-building-a-di-container-using-tdd/) on creating the [Funq](http://funq.codeplex.com/) DI Container. Funq is lightweight and fast but lacks some of the bells and whistles of the larger, more established frameworks.

I use the Funq-derived [Munq](http://munq.codeplex.com/) which is also lightweight and fast and is a simple way to add a DI Container to MVC3 projects via Nuget. Up to now I haven't found any need to move to a different framework - Munq has been very adequate.

```
PM> install-package Munq.MVC3
```

This will add `App_Start\MunqMvc3Startup.cs` to the project, and this is where dependencies should be registered.